# miktex platex build fail with tarticle class

Tags: miktex, platex

miktex 22.7 fixed the `can't build platex format` issue. after i upgrade my miktex to 22.7, i try this MWE with platex:

```
\documentclass{tarticle}
\begin{document}
で日本語を書きましょう！
\end{document}
```

but it builds fail. the platex.log is:

```
2022-07-19 21:57:57,603+0800 WARN  platex - security risk: running with elevated privileges
2022-07-19 21:57:57,605+0800 INFO  platex - this is MiKTeX-EPTEX 1.1.0 (220214) (MiKTeX 22.7)
2022-07-19 21:57:57,605+0800 INFO  platex - allowing known shell commands
2022-07-19 21:57:57,773+0800 FATAL platex - invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
2022-07-19 21:57:57,773+0800 INFO  platex - this process (1660) finishes with exit code 1
2022-07-19 21:57:57,773+0800 WARN  platex.core - still open: mwe.log
2022-07-19 21:57:57,773+0800 WARN  platex.core - still open: mwe.aux
```

but i try to build this MWE with texlive 2022, it build successfully.
i compare the `tarticle` in miktex and texlive 2022, they are same.

the log don't have more information that which file and which line have the `invalid UTF-8 byte sequence`, and why `invalid UTF-8 byte sequence`? because texlive 2022 build the MWE successfully with UTF-8 also.

the log don't have more information that which file and which line have the `invalid UTF-8 byte sequence`.

how to get more information about this issue? and how to fix this issue?

PS: i installed these packages in miktex for using platex/uplatex:

```
japanese-otf
japanese-otf-uptex
ptex-base
ptex-fontmaps
ptex-fonts
ptex2pdf
platex-tools
platex
uptex-base
uptex-fonts
uplatex
zhmetrics-uptex
```

Comment: it probably has something to do with the kanji encodings, but the best is to open an issue in the miktex tracker.

Comment: I'm surprised to find that MiKTeX now contains pTeX and related packages ...

Comment: Already fixed? I don’t have MiKTeX installed https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1129

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA Yes, this issue already fixed.